# How are threads implemented in Windows 7?

Tags: multithreading, windows-7, concurrency, synchronization

Microsoft introduced that Window 7 has improved threading subsystem introducing Hybrid (N:M user-space / kernel space threads mapping).

Does somebody know the specifics of threading implementation. While there are a lot of materials (and obviously open source for Linux NPTL implementation) and some info on Mac OS threads implementation, I couldn't find any info on Windows 7 threading implementation specifics.

Especially I'm interested about:

- Synchronization primitives implementation (like futexes in Linux)
- Thread queueing policies
- Thread data structures
- Thread local storage implementation
- Memory allocation and deallocation
- ... other threading-related features I've forgotten to mention

Would be appreciate about any provided info and / or links.

Comment: Presumably somebody in the bowels of Microsoft knows...

Comment: You should go looking for "windows internals" type sites, I believe there is some kind of bible on the topic. As it is a printed book, you might have to wait for an edition covering this.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a SO question. More Super User, if you ask me

Comment: Can you give a reference that they introduced that? I find nothing about it, and I doubt they would do that.

Comment: @usr, there's a remark in Wikipedia (look Hybrid implementations and fiber implementations chapters below). As the source isn't mentioned there, I can't say it's 100% true, but I cannot remember where else I saw that, sorry for that.

Comment: @usr, found something valuable - user mode scheduling of threads: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Dave-Probert-Inside-Windows-7-User-Mode-Scheduler-UMS, I'll possibly think of making a self answer, since seems like it's what I've been seeking for. The speaker is Windows Kerner Architect.

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko those are technically not hybrid threads. But anyway, glad you found what you were looking for.

Comment: @usr, thanks, and you're right, those are just user-level threads (like fibers but sith separate contexts), will try to go deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing drastic was changed in Windows 7, just a minor improvement in the "thread mapping" (aka thread affinity).  The scheduler improves the odds that a thread stays scheduled on a particular core and doesn't jump from one core to another.  This is good for power consumption, reducing cache thrashing and supporting Intel Nehalem and AMD Phenom II, architectures that support per-core low-power states.  No software considerations apply, that I can think of anyway.